# How to find a linear approximation at a critical point for a potential of a conservative field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, linearized-theory

I am trying to understand how [Arnold derives](https://books.google.com/books?id=UOQlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA19) his tangent equation for branches of a critical point in phase space.

Why is the slope at critical point in the phase space- $\sqrt{-U^{''}(\xi)}$ :

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Energy level sets $E=\frac{1}{2} y^2 + U(x)$. Now, around the critical point you can Taylor-Expand your potential as $U(x) \approx U(\xi) + \frac{1}{2} U''(\xi) (x-\xi)^2 $, where $E = U(\xi)$. Hence you are left with
$y^2 + U''(\xi) (x-\xi)^2=0$. Solving this will give you $y = \pm \sqrt{-U''(\xi)} (x-\xi)$. Since we are sitting at maximum $U''(\xi) < 0$, the square root is well defined. As for the sign difference, i am unsure if arnold is using different conventions …